# C / C++ Char Pointers to Pointers and Arrays

Tags: c++, c, blackberry-10

There is a function with a header such as this:

```
BPS_API int dialog_event_get_filebrowse_filepaths(bps_event_t* event,
                                            char** file_paths[], int* num_paths);
```

This is from BlackBerry 10's Native SDK for anyone wondering (it can be found [here](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/native/reference/com.qnx.doc.bps.lib_ref/com.qnx.doc.bps.lib_ref/topic/dialog_event_get_filebrowse_filepaths.html)).

The question is: what am I supposed to provide as the second argument. This function should populate an array of char pointers in order to return the file paths selected.

I tried to call it this way:

```
char* ar[2];
dialog_event_get_filebrowse_filepaths(event, &ar, &number_paths);
```

And I am getting an error from QNX Momentics as such:

```
cannot convert 'char * (*)[2]' to char * * * for argument 2 to int
dialog_event_get_filebrowse_filepaths(bps_event_t *, char * * *, int *)
```

This seems the most logical way to call it. It needs the memory address of an array of pointer in order to set them, as far as I understand.
However, if I declare:

```
char** ar[2];
dialog_event_get_filebrowse_filepaths(event, ar, &number_paths);
```

It works, but this way I created an array of pointers to char pointers (an array of arrays of char*). Is this what I should really provide to the function?

Comment: @Macmade It may be a beginner's mistake, but your irony doesn't seem to help me much. Care to explain more in detail?

Comment: The function wants `char** file_paths[]` an array of pointers ot pointers to `char` (probably, an array of pointers to `char`-arrays is the intended usage), so give that to it, as your second example. Maybe you ought to allocate storage for the array-members before calling.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer I doubt I need to allocate anything since the documentation says that the things returned should be cleared with bps_free(), an SDK function. Macmade is probably right - I probably needed to cast to (char***) in the first example. It works that way.

Comment: Actually, I believe the function wants a pointer to char* file_paths[].  Slight difference ;)

Comment: @Alex One would need to consult the documentation. The way it's written suggests it wants an array of pointers to C strings. But as a function argument, that's a `char ***`, so Vaughn Ctao's guess might be right. Casting a 'pointer to array of `char*`' to that type might be the right thing, but doesn't correspond well to the signature.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Yes, you are probably right on that Vaughn Ctao is right (talking about indirection, heh). As I said in a comment, I will test that, and if it returns correct results, I will mark it as an answer. However, they have chosen a very inconvenient way of declaring parameters knowing all the confusion with pointers and arrays of chars.

Comment: I'm not saying anybody's right (or wrong). I haven't sufficient information about the function for that.

Comment: Nor do I, that's the problem, the documentation says only as much.

Comment: @Alex: what **does** the documentation say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation really should have been more explicit, but I'm pretty sure this is what the function expects:

First, a few rules of thumb to help decode the function:

- the type is really equivalent to a `char***`. This means we have to find a meaning for three pointers.
- a string in C is a `char*` (leaving out the `const` for brevity). As we expect the function to populate an array of strings, that's one `*` accounted for.
- an array in C is generally represented by a pointer. So that's the second `*`.
- "output parameters" can be handled in one of two ways: either the caller allocates memory, and passes a pointer, telling callee where to write its data, or the caller does *not* allocate any memory, and simply passes in a pointer to a pointer. The callee will then modify the "innermost" pointer to point to a chunk of memory allocated by the callee itself. The second approach would account for the last `*`. This also explains the documentation note that `The memory holding these values must be freed using bps_free() when no longer needed` -- because the memory was allocated by the library function, rather than by you, it is important that you use the correct `free` function.

So, the function should be called like this:

```
char** strs;
dialog_event_get_filebrowse_filepaths(foo, &strs, bar);
```

When the function returns, `strs` will point to the first entry of an array of strings allocated by `dialog_event_get_filebrowse_filepaths`.

Comment: Thanks for deciphering. It is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but I suspect it should be called like this:

```
char** ar = 0;
dialog_event_get_filebrowse_filepaths(event, &ar, &number_paths);
```

The fact that it is declared with array syntax is confusing, but this would be a common way for a C-style function to return an allocated array of strings.

Comment: This would certainly compile, I tried it already, but I haven't tested it yet. If it works after I test, I will mark this as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

the function will return a string-array and the length via arguments, you can use it like:

```
char **ar=0;
int i,number_paths = 0;
dialog_event_get_filebrowse_filepaths(event, &ar, &number_paths);
for( i=0; i<number_paths; i++ )
  puts( ar[i] );
```

and you can/must free the memory ( see lib-docu ) like:

```
for( i=0; i<number_paths; i++ )
  free( ar[i] );
free( ar );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some (non-Blackberry) code that should satisfy the compiler:

```
char *file_paths[];
iret = dialog_event_get_filebrowse_filepaths (event, &ar, &number_paths);
```

The point is

1) do *not* assign a fixed length in the declaration.

2) pass addressof (&) array pointer to your function

3) make sure *somebody* (either the API function, or you) allocates the array, and all the strings in the array

Comment: If I don't assign a fixed length, the compiler says: storage size of file_paths isn't known

Comment: `char *file_paths[];` is not valid C-array definition; which C compiler will compile this?